# TinyMCE 6: how to reconfigure toolbar after init() has already run?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

With TinyMCE 5.x and older, I used to be able to run `editor.setMode("readonly")`, adjust `editor.settings.toolbar` and then call `editor.setMode("design")` to be able to reconfigure toolbar contents after the `editor.init()` had already been run. I already figured out that `editor.setMode()` has been replaced with `editor.mode.set()`.

However, the whole `editor.settings` API seems to have vanished and TinyMCE 6.x documentation only shows `toolbar` examples with `init()`. I cannot notice any info about this API being removed in migration guide at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/ either. The `editor.settings` has documentation for TinyMce 5.x at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/

**Is it possible to reconfigure TinyMCE 6.x options `toolbar` or `plugins` after `editor.init()` has already been executed?**

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/#mceaddeditor-and-mcetoggleeditor